# Validate Terraform Resource Name Against Custom Naming Convention Policy with checkov

Tags: checkov

**Description**
I would like to validate the resource name of a Terraform resource against a custom naming convention policy. Specifically, I want to ensure that the resource name does not contain dashes (-) within it. However, I'm unable to find a suitable method to accomplish this.

**Example Code**

`resource "google_storage_bucket" "bucket-prd" { }`
Environment
Checkov Version: 2.3.311

**Expected Behavior**
I expect to be able to check the resource name (bucket-prd) against a custom naming convention policy that prohibits the use of dashes (-) within the name. However, I have been unable to find a way to achieve this.

Please provide guidance or suggest any available methods to validate the resource name against the desired custom policy. Thank you.

As i searched in the documentations from checkov i couldn't find anything related to resource_name within terraform code.